# Where to stay at Guangzhou, I am a vegetarian

Tags: food-and-drink, hotels, dietary-restrictions, guangzhou

I am 68 and planning to travel to Guangzhou in China with wife. We are vegetarians. We like to stay in a crowded area where we can walk a lot. Also we would sometimes like to cook our food. A supermarket nearby will be to great advantage.

Answer (score 2):

[Dianping](http://www.dianping.com/) is a food and restaurant guide website in China. It lists out [most of the vegetarian restaurant in Guangzhou](http://www.dianping.com/search/category/4/10/g109).

The website is written in Chinese only. Use [baidu translate](http://fanyi.baidu.com/) and 
[baidu map](http://map.baidu.com/) to find out more information about the restaurant.

In addition, although they claim they are vegetarian restaurants but no certification is done. And not every restaurant offers English menu.

---

For supermarket, search keyword "广州 超市" in baidu map and you can find the location easy.

There are several supermarket chain in Guangzhou, including 家乐福(Walmart), 百佳 (From Hong Kong), 好又多(From Taiwan), 华润万家 (Chinese firm but cooperate with Tesco), 大润发(From Taiwan), 乐购(Tesco). You can find most vegetable and other foods you need in larger supermarket.

Comment: Is Cantonese food culture generally vegetarian friendly ?

Comment: I dont know. But Buddhist are vegan.

Comment: @Blackbird57: I've heard it said that Cantonese cuisine includes "everything that flies except planes, and everything in the ocean except boats". Non-meat dishes are usually side dishes.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill Cantonese eat many strange food but not every type can be found in major restaurant. And they serve seafood/riverfood and vegetable as main dishes

Comment: I've been in Guangzhou for the past month and have seen a couple of signs for places claiming to be vegetarian restaurants. At least one seemed to have gone out of business but other than that they do seem to exist here. It's a **very** big city.

Comment: @Blackbird57 Generally, but Buddhist cuisine (素食) is vegetarian and sufficiently common that there are restaurants devoted to it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_cuisine